# In Mirth how do I retry destinations and block till response received?

Tags: mirth

We have a Mirth channel (synchronized) going to 4 destinations.

The first 3 destinations are web service calls (HTTP Sender) which are simply REST calls to get some basic data.

The 4th channel relies on the previous 3 destinations to have been completed cleanly.  The data from those previous destinations are used in the 4th destination's transformer and the outgoing message is modified accordingly.

When the channel was initially released, the destinations were not set to "use persistent queues".  Occasionally one of the web service calls would timeout.  When this happens the content of the response (paraphrased) was "Error:HTTP Timeout....".

The channel was updated to use persistent queues.  Now the response is "Message is queued".

In either case the 4th destination is called despite the result of previous destinations.  And the response data is the Mirth error/warning message instead of data from the HTTP call.

What we need is for Mirth to queue on a destination and not continue until the destination has been successful.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: I wish I could know the answer,but I don't.let me try. But this is good question.

Comment: @Sid - Maybe you could add the question here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51758/healthcare-it - You can only add 6 questions - so I don't have any left....

Comment: Hey Chronofish..Can you paste the export .xml of your current setup on this question. Its hard to visualize the channel from reading here.

Comment: btw I just added this question on the other site :)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, if anyone is looking for the answer to this, Mirth 3.x seems to be able to handle this case. ChronoFish received an answer to this on the Mirth forums. Even though it is a rather complex solution, a full example is provided in that answer.

Link to answer over at Mirth forums: http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=9048

Comment: I totally don't get that downvote. Is it better to NOT to have a pointer to the answer?

Comment: I don't agree with the "downvote" but generally I think the "community" likes to see answers rather than links to answers - unless the link is to a StackOverflow answer - which is acceptable - (but then the question would be closed as "duplicate").  It is an effort to maintain StackOverflow's credibility as a high quality QA site.